# Cross Domain HTML .load()

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

First of all, I apologize if this question gets asked frequently! I've looked at most of the suggested solutions and tried to implement them but nothing seems to work. I'm new to javascript and doing this for my Web Development class.

**My question:**
I am trying to load a **part** of HTML from Google's currency exchange page into two divs on my page. I can't embed a screenshot here because I'm new so here's an imgur link that shows what I'm trying to accomplish. https://i.stack.imgur.com/K5ZSQ.jpg

I'm using the following two lines of code to do that

```
$('.conversionRate').load('https://www.google.com/finance?q='+currency1+currency2+'&ei=UUJ8V6njIJHDeqDaicAC .pr');

$('.dataTable').load('https://www.google.com/finance?q='+currency1+currency2+'&ei=UUJ8V6njIJHDeqDaicAC .currencies');
```

This works perfectly fine on localhost but as soon as i upload my PHP file to the server, the requests seem to come back empty handed and no data is displayed in those two divs. Is this a

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin
```

issue? Is my approach by using .load() completely wrong? If so, what's a better way to get a specific part of HTML from a different domain?

**[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xCSla.png**

Answer (score 0):

Just as **WILL** said, you should consider using a **proxy PHP file** (*there are many google tutorial on how to do that on PHP*) and then loading that file using jQuery .load().

```
$("div").load("proxy.php");
```

and on **proxy.php:**

```
<?=file_get_contents("example.com")?>
```

It won't fully work, so you would have to do some script and style tweaks. Hope it helps :D